# GetSystemPowerStatus for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I saw the winbase.h (WINAPI) file (kernel32.dll) in windows phone 8 sdk which has the function :

> GetSystemPowerStatus which will return the battery
>   status(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS)

.
Question is this throws and exception on the emulator, not tested on handset (waiting to get one)

I have used

```
 [DllImport("Kernel32")]
   private static extern Boolean GetSystemPowerStatus( SystemPowerStatus sps );
```

the code complies but throws exception at runtime.

any idea will this work on handset, or this is not supported at all for windows phone 8 ?

Answer (score 2):

As AnderZubi has said this is not a supported Win32 API on Windows Phone 8. However there is an equivalent [WinRT API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.devices.power.battery%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can call from your native C/C++ code. This is very similar to the C# API Martin posted.

If you are already in C/C++ using the WinRT version may save you needing to bridge between C++ and C#. If you are starting out a new app which will just use XAML/C# then Martin's answer will be simpler.

For example:

```
int WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent::GetBatteryRemainingPercent()
{
    auto battery = Windows::Phone::Devices::Power::Battery::GetDefault();
    int remainingPercent = battery->RemainingChargePercent;
    return remainingPercent;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, I have seen this api and it works, but it justs gives very basic information, I need to check the voltage, battery type, battery performance (degraded or not) and all the parameters which are defined in SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS structure. is there any equivalent api to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access battery info and the bool property, if phone is on charger or not, you can use this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;
using Windows.Phone.Devices.Power;

namespace Core.Helpers
{
    public class BatteryHelper
    {
        public static int BateryLevel
        {
            get
            {
                return Battery.GetDefault().RemainingChargePercent;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsCharging
        {
            get
            {
                return DeviceStatus.PowerSource == PowerSource.External;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetSystemPowerStatus is not in the list of supported Win32 APIs for Windows Phone 8:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662956(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Is there any equivalent api which windows phone 8 supports ?

Comment: As far as I know, no. The only additional info you can retreieve is if the phone is in power saving mode, using the PowerManager API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.system.power.powermanager(v=vs.105).aspx